# What does "loading a class" mean with the Android Runtime (ART) when using reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, dalvik, android-runtime

I try to understand the process of ART when using reflection. As it can be seen in the simple example below, the `DexClassLoader` is used to load a class from the DEX-file. The question now is what is ART doing internally when loading a class?

From other sources, I found out that the previously used `dalvikVM` loads the bytecode of the class into memory and initializes static content during loading. The bytecode can then be interpreted by the `dalvikVM` (e.g. creating an instance of that class).

The Android documentation states that ART uses Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation, which converts the bytecode in a DEX-file into some optimized code that is then executed on the device.

So, if I load a class via reflection is it compiled again and then executed? Or does it work the same way it did with the `dalvikVM` by loading and interpreting the bytecode?

**Example:**

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
DexClassLoader dexClassLoader = new DexClassLoader("path/to/dex", null, ".", cl);

Class<?> loadedClass = dexClassLoader.loadClass("com.package.MyClass");
            
Object instance = loadedClass.newInstance();

Method method = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("myMethodName", String.class);

Object result = method.invoke(instance, "my method input");
```

I would appreciate any additional information on this topic. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I found out that using the above example creates a `.prof` file for my DEX-file in a folder called 'oat' located in the same directory as the original DEX-file.

From [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/jit-compiler) I know that the process of running an app is that the DEX-file is simply loaded and interpreted if there are no OAT-files. During execution profiles are created and the app is compiled with `dex2oat`. So I assume that with my example the content of the DEX-file is simply interpreted, which then creates the .prof-files that could be used when executing the code again.